# Updating apk only for specific version

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-market-filtering

**EDIT:** The question statement was not the correct, so I have updated it.

I have uploaded an Android app on Play Store. Now want to make a change in my android app and thus update it for the users. But I want the update to be available only to users of a particular version of android (say users with API 14 or higher).

Answer (score 1):

Set:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

In your Android Manifest

**Edit:**
Yes, that would need to have a different build. If you want t have only one apk and have certain features to only appear in Android Api 14+.

You can check at runtime like this (requires Api 4):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
```

If you are supporting Api below 4. Use this instead:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK)>=14){
```

(**Note:** this is deprecated)

Comment: But wouldn't this mean building a separate app for guys with API 14+ and for those with below 14?

Answer (score 0):

in code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSIOS_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    do stuff
} else {
    do old stuff
}
```

in resources

```
res/layout-v14/layout_for_v14_and_higher.xml
res/values-v14/values_for_v14_and_higher.xml
res/drawable-v14-hdpi/drawable_new.png
```